# Detect collision with static collider only

Tags: unity, c#

Is this possible to detect collision with static colliders only I check it is not working. I dont want to use rigidbody or character controller with my box collider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static colliders shouldn't collide with one another, and they should not be used on objects that will move (such as a player).  You may want to give more information about what it is that you are doing, but for most purposes, two static colliders will never hit.  If one object is moving, it should have a rigidbody if physics are applied.  Otherwise it should use a non-static collider.

Edit: thanks @philipp

Comment: *"If one object is moving, it needs to have a rigidbody"* - that's wrong. You only need a rigidbody when you want to move it *with the physics engine*. It is perfectly fine to have an object without a rigidbody and move it by manipulating its transform directly. But it is correct that the object should have a non-static collider in that case because static colliders are only fast as long as they don't move. It *is* possible to move them without causing any bugs, but you shouldn't because moving a static collider can be very performance-heavy.

Comment: @Philipp Yes, thank you for the correction. Non-static (non-stationary) objects shouldn't use static colliders. And yes, non-rigidbody objects can collide but cannot have Unity physics applied.

Comment: @Philipp my understanding is that, in Unity, the collider is automatically treated as static if it doesn't have a rigidbody attached. The usual course of action I know of is to attach a rigidbody marked `isKinematic = true` so that you can manually drive its motion without interference from physics or the performance penalty of moving a static collider.

Comment: healthy info but what is there any way available to check collision with rigidbody

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan  -  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.OnCollisionEnter.html